# Is there any function convert Extjs4 root tree node to button group?

Tags: extjs4.2

I am not sure what i want is existing yet. I am using Extjs4+.
So i want convert bellow tree to group button [Students(drop down menu),Teachers (drop down menu),Staff (drop down menu)] i want something like Microsoft word menu.

Current tree:

```
- Students
    - Student List
    - Student Absence List
- Teachers
    - Teacher List
    - Teacher Absence List
- Staff
    - Staff List
    - Staff Absence List
    //Three data respond from server with Json.
```

Comment: yes, we can able to achieve it @Meas, You need to iterate the tree node and create a menu items and add those in the toolbar dynamically using add option in tooolbar.

Comment: Could you give an example code?